# How do I implement TLS in my axis2 web service client?

Tags: java, apache-axis, java-ws

I have an axis2 web service client running on a j2ee server (jboss 4.0.4) that has been working with a web service hosted on tomcat. Recently the tomcat admin turned on TLS, and now my axis2 client does not work. How do I turn on TLS for my axis2 client?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: See the solution proposed here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605878/3969110](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605878/3969110) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We had a handshake exception after the host discontinued support for SSL protocol and accepted only TLS. This fix worked for us on Java 1.6.  Now we do this before sending the request like we did before.

```
 SSLProtocolSocketFactory spsf = new SSLProtocolSocketFactory();

 socket = (SSLSocket) spsf.createSocket(host, port);
 socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1"});

 socket.startHandshake();

 //After the request...
 socket.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add https.protocols=TLSv1 system property to your axis2 web service client. This switches off the old SSLv3 and SSLv2Hello protocols.