# Unable to connect to TLS 1.2 using HTTPclient 3.1

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a running code that i am already using  to connect to a server using SSL. The API i am using is commons-httpclient-3.1.jar and i cant not upgrade the jar. 
The servers have upgraded to only use TSL 1.2.
Now my existing code is not working.
My current code is

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://XYZserver");
        post.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        File f = new File("C://sampleXml.xml");
        RequestEntity entity = new FileRequestEntity(f, "Application/xml");
        post.setRequestEntity(entity);  
        int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

If i modify my code as per link [How to force Commons HTTPClient 3.1 to use TLS 1.2 only for HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587141/how-to-force-commons-httpclient-3-1-to-use-tls-1-2-only-for-https) then my code is working fine.

I have few questions (As i was unable to find their answers?)

- Why do we require a separate class CustomHttpsSocketFactory. Is it possible to modify existing code to use TLS

  - Is there any other way to do?